# How can I drain a dishwasher without an adjacent sink trap?

Tags: basement, dishwasher, drain-waste-vent

I am finishing the basement and have already done the plumbing and framing. Now I consider to add cabinet to a room. The cabinet will have a dishwasher so I have to tackle the drain connection. I do not want to add a sink.

The future laundry room is across the wall. The route between the dishwasher to the sink drain/vent pipe is about 2 feet long and involves two 90 degree turns.

What is the simplest connection in this case?

Comment: It's not at all clear what your concern is.  Most dishwashers come with a flex-hose output which will allow you to route it through almost any path. You'll need some sort of Y-connector to hook the hose into the drain (the other side of the Y is from the laundry machine.

Comment: That is the normal way. However since the drywall is not up yet, I prefer having ABS pipe inside the wall, then connecting the hose to the pipe under the cabinet.

Comment: I agree that I'm not sure what the concern is. A trap does not require a sink, as the clothes washer's standpipe demonstrates.You do also want an air inlet on that drain to ensure against syphoning, but that can be solved exactly as for a sink, or as for the washing machine with a standpipe that the dishwasher's  exhaust hose fits loosely into. Just leave off the sink. What's the difficulty?